# Android: Admob interstital ad setAdListener not working

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I added setAdListener for interstital ad, but none of functions getting called on any event, ad showing up properly without any issues.

Same code working fine in case of SMART_BANNER.

Find sample code below

```
InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));

interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

    public void onAdLoaded() {
        Log.i("AdEvent: ", "onAdLoaded");
    }

    public void onAdOpened() {
        Log.i("AdEvent: ", "onAdOpened");
    }
});

if (!interstitial.isLoaded()) {
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code that you are showing.

But in order to get an Interstitial Ad, you need to call `interstitial.loadAd(adRequest)`. Without that nothing will happen.

Comment: Actually i loaded ad in code but forgot to mention here in question

Answer (score 0):

1. You forgot to call

   ```
   interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
   ```
2. Check your logcat, if there is any problem with interstitial, its will not show.
3. You should add **override** in your `onAdLoaded` and  `onAdOpened`. Also add `onAdFailedToLoad` to check what error is ocurring :

   ```
   interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
       @Override
       public void onAdLoaded() {
           Log.i("AdEvent: ", "onAdLoaded");
       }
       @Override
       public void onAdOpened() {
           Log.i("AdEvent: ", "onAdOpened");
       }
       @Override
       public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
           String message = String.format("onAdFailedToLoad (%s)", getErrorReason(errorCode));
           Log.d("AdEvent", message);
       }
   });

   /** Gets a string error reason from an error code. */
   private String getErrorReason(int errorCode) {
     switch(errorCode) {
       case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR:
         return "Internal error";
       case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST:
         return "Invalid request";
       case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR:
         return "Network Error";
       case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL:
         return "No fill";
       default:
         return "Unknown error";
     }
   }
   ```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Actually i loaded ad in code but forgot to mention here in question.

Comment: Ads loading properly so it's not calling function onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode);

Comment: Try @Override public void onAdClosed() ?

Comment: there is something that dont match, **SMART_BANNER** is for Admob Banner, Interstitial is different, I dont see where you call your `interstitial.show()` to show Interstitial

Answer (score 0):

try implemeng **onAdFailedToLoad** and check whether there is any issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response guys.

It's actually setting setAdListener() twice, so the one set first is working & ignores the second listener. My Bad.

Once again thanks for your reponses.

Comment: The moral to the story is to show **ALL** the relevant code in your question, otherwise we all spend time guessing about what you may or may not have done.